# C++ For loop problem

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have a loop that takes two inputs, a last name and an ID, then converts it to a user id. The  code looks like this:

```
   void User::setUserid(string ln, string id){
        string temp = "0";
        string temp2 = "0";
        for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++){
            temp += ln[k]; 
        }
        for (int i = id.length()-2; i<id.length(); i++){
            temp2 += id[i];
        }
        userid = temp+temp2;

    }
```

For some reason if I comment out the first for loop it will compile and build. Any ideas why the code crashes?

Comment: And what `ln` and `id` did you provide?

Comment: Do you have some way of knowing that ln is always length 6?

Comment: And if you don't comment out the first loop, what happens?  What do you mean by "crashes"?  Does it refuse to compile?  Are there any error messages?

Comment: It crashes when last name = Adams, which is 5 characters. So I believe it has something to do with that

Comment: @DanielRHicks when I run it just popups with an error screen telling me "Debug assertion failed" and asks to abort.

Comment: If it crashes when you supply a 5 character name, I'd suspect that the name is somehow getting fed to the first loop.  Perhaps you have your parms crossed between the call and the actual method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `ln` guaranteed to have at least six characters? You may be shooting past the end of the string.

In any event, you've chosen a slow and complicated way to copy parts of strings around. This should suffice:

```
void User::setUserid(string ln, string id){
    userid = "0" + ln.substr(0, 6) + "0" + id.substr(id.size() - 2);
}
```

Note that this will produce a shorter userid if `ln.size() < 6` and throw `out_of_range` if `id.size() < 2`.

Comment: It crashes when last name = Adams  so I believe it has something to do with that

Comment: @Nick Oh you have got to be kidding!

Comment: @Konrad Sorry, I'm learning how to program. This stuff isn't immediately clear to me.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly and the code is much less convoluted than mine, haha :)

Comment: @Nick: No worries. Keep at it, and don't be discouraged by negative comments.

Answer (score 1):

The string `ln` might have less characters than 6 - `ln[k]` will be out of bounds.

Note that the code will crash if the `id` string contains less then two characters (`i` will be negative).